# Find difficulty in enumerating by Latex in Python markdown

Tags: enumerate, python, markdown

Our professor asked us not to use raw html to reproduce the following text.
[image]

I tried to use the following codes to achieve such enumeration format but failed. Could anyone give me some hint? Am I on the correct direction

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What has your question to do with TeX?

Comment: Kindly check out basics about Latex, e.g. here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX , with focus on list structures https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures .

Comment: Actually, I am totally new to Tex or Latex. If I posted the question in a wrong place, please forgive my fault.

Comment: It is not clear, what is your problem: Please provide small, complete document, which begin with`\documentclas` and end with `\end{document}` in which you show, what you try so far and where you stuck. Showed code fragment should work fine.

Comment: @Cooper: What format is the output you're trying to generate? HTML?

Comment: Maybe it's best to ask your professor which approach he had in mind :)

Comment: You should use markdown. See here: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-ultimate-markdown-cheat-sheet-3d3976b31a0#2c6e